# Is there an easy way to get user reputation via API?

Tags: support, api, reputation

I am looking for an easy way to access user reputation so that I can write a small react component and display my rep on my portfolio site.

I want to make this package available on NPM and have minimal config for the end user. So ideally, they enter in their user_id and if necessary an API key or something.

Going through oAuth to get access token and then having to renew access token seems very convoluted just to retrieve reputation for a user, but maybe it's the only way?

Are there any endpoints like [this post](https://stackapps.com/questions/3428/whats-the-best-way-to-get-all-available-data-related-to-a-users-reputation) talks about where you can make a simple get request like

https://stackoverflow.com/ajax/users/14343/rep/day/1304035200

except return all reputation and preferably formatted in JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is not clear.  If you **just want a user's reputation** merely do a `GET` of [the API `/users/{ids}` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids).  Like so:

[api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/3528590?site=stackoverflow&filter=!qGQfndHk_gIjJ(.lwtNt](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/3528590?site=stackoverflow&filter=!qGQfndHk_gIjJ(.lwtNt)

(The custom filter is just to remove all the other stuff we don't care about.)

OAuth is not needed, and even a `key` is optional. (It just increases the quota for the IP making the request.)
You can also register for a key and then reuse it for any number of users (no need for them to get their own key in this case).

---

If you are looking for daily reputation, or changes, or events/history then the API has other routes for that:

- [/users/{ids}/reputation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-on-users)
- [/users/{ids}/reputation-history](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-history)
- [/users/{id}/reputation-history/full](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/full-reputation-history)  This one *does* require OAuth.